# ClassLoader issue with GroovyShell when parsing own DSL

Tags: groovy, osgi

I try to execute my custom DSL with `GroovyShell`:

```
class DslScriptLoader {

  static runScript(String dsl) {
    CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration(CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT)
    config.scriptBaseClass = 'com.my.MyDslBaseClass'
    config.addCompilationCustomizers(
       new ASTTransformationCustomizer(TypeChecked)
    )
    assert DslScriptLoader.classLoader.loadClass('groovy.lang.GroovyObject') != null
    def shell = new GroovyShell(new Binding(), config)
    def script = shell.parse(dsl)
    // ...
  }
}
```

When I run this locally in my IDE, everything works fine. But as soon as I run this in a OSGi-based container, I get the following exception:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        ... 66 more
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35    1 error
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1075)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:694)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:706)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:742)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:733)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$parse.call(Unknown Source)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    error   23-Mar-2016 14:14:35        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
```

As you can see, the error happens when `GroovyShell` tries to parse my DSL. Loading the class `groovy.lang.GroovyObject` in the statement before is perfectly possible. Also, if I try to explicitly pass the class loader like follows, the same error happens:

```
def shell = new GroovyShell(DslScriptLoader.classLoader, new Binding(), config)
```

Any ideas what causes this problem? Which class loader is `GroovyShell` using when not the one I pass in the ctor?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: You have deployed groovy-all in your osgi container ? by default, groovy use the classloader of the groovy bundle, which has a Dynamic-ImportPackage statement : it can see all the classes in the container

Comment: I bundle groovy-all.jar together with my JAR in the META-INF/lib and reference it in my MANIFEST.MF like follows:Bundle-ClassPath: .,META
 -INF/lib/groovy-all-2.4.4.jar